# accept all incoming emails with unknown name and redirect into a known user with postfix

Tags: email, postfix, redirect

when i send mail into my `root@mydomain.com` address, this works.

but when i send mail into another inexistent user mail address (like `sdfsdfdsf@mydomain.com`) this reject the e-mail:

```
Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table (state 13).
```

How can i accept all mails (and redirect the 'unknown addresses' into `root@mydomain.com`)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know postfix at all, but maybe there is a way you can set *@mydomain.com as that user's address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the config parameter [user_relay](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#luser_relay) to set the catchall user. And to not block non-existing users `local_recipient_maps` must me empty. So in your case:

```
luser_relay = root@mydomain.com
local_recipient_maps =
```

Comment: hmmm, this works, but only works sometimes :S
if i send mail into dfdfsdff@mydomain.com works but i send mail into d9f9sdf8s9df89sdf89sdf8@mydomain.com doesn't works, how can it works arbitrarily?

Comment: The error that the server returned is: 550 550 sorry, no mailbox here by that name (#5.1.1) (state 13).
but this only occurs randomly

Comment: @felix46r If it seems to randomly fail, then you probably have something else affecting it.  What are the log messages when it fails?  Did you reload postfix after changing the configuration?  If not then some smtpd processes may still be working with the old config.

Comment: @dsh today works perfectly, problem solved, thanks to all (:

Answer (score 0):

You might try the virtual_alias_maps answer (shows as 4th answer for me) from [postfix - how do you redirect all emails to one user, eg *@example.com → user@example.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/23717/postfix-how-do-you-redirect-all-emails-to-one-user-eg-example-com-userex)

I had and solved this problem many years ago but do not have a copy of what I did. But the above sure looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

That is called a "catch-all" address.

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#luser_relay

> **Local catch-all address**
>
> When the local(8) delivery agent finds that a message recipient does not exist, the message is normally returned to the sender ("user unknown"). Sometimes it is desirable to forward mail for non-existing recipients to another machine. For this purpose you can specify an alternative destination with the luser_relay configuration parameter.