# Postfix: accept all incoming mails and write them to separate files per username

Tags: postfix, email-server

Similar to the following one: [accept all incoming emails with unknown name and redirect into a known user with postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/414282/accept-all-incoming-emails-with-unknown-name-and-redirect-into-a-known-user-with)

Is is possible to configure Postfix to allow all incoming mails except store them in `/var/spool/mail/` based on receiver's username? (eg: if a mail is coming to `/(.*)/@mydomain.tld`, store it in `/var/spool/mail/${1}` file)

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up postfix with virtual domains**

**[This article](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_postfix_with_virtual_domains)** is about virtual domains, but it includes how to configure and map vmailbox and that is what you are most likely looking for.  You will get different directories that have username/{new,cur,tmp}

Remember to run the postmap commands any time you make changes to the mapping.