# Forward mail to "root" user even if RCPT TO field is different? (Postfix)

Tags: postfix

I have a script that basically connects via telnet to my postfix server and sends email.
Of course, it accepts only email when the field "RCPT TO" is like "root@example.com" or "user@example.com". Is there a way to forward all the emails to "root@example.com" even if the RCPT TO field is set like "user@gmail.com" or "user@yahoo.com"?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Creating a “fake” open relay to capture non-relayable outgoing mail with postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/434638/creating-a-fake-open-relay-to-capture-non-relayable-outgoing-mail-with-postfix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add gmail.com and yahoo.com in postfix `mydestination` parameter.

Comment: can I also send "user@domain.com" email to "root@domain.com" ?

Comment: Yes, edit /etc/aliases file and put `user:root` , then run `newaliases` command.

Comment: thank you very much! Last thing: is it possible to do it even if I don't know the exact username? If I'm not mistaken if there's no "user" on the system it can receive the email right?
The idea is to send all the emails to root so that I can see them, even if the user doesn't exist

Comment: Sure you can, with catch all address like @domain.com. Here is a good intro http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/

Answer (score 2):

@Snakethesniper,
Since you need a copy of mail for a) mail sent to all valid users and b) mail sent to invalid/non-existent users. I suggest the following.

a) add the following line to your main.cf to get a copy of all valid user mails

```
always_bcc = root
```

b) setup the catch-all configuration following the link provided by @Tutul earlier to get a copy of all invalid/non-existent users.

Based what you asked and your follow-up questions, I think you need both settings to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This only solves the OP's question for mails that are already accepted and delivered, but he asked for all mails.

Comment: @sebix, That is correct. I clarified my response above.